# Postfix/Dovecot: mail queue is empty, but emails still don't get delivered until the server is rebooted

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

I am running an Ubuntu 22.04 server with Postfix, Dovecot, Amavis, and SpamAssassin. A couple months ago, I noticed I hadn't gotten emails from the server in about a month. I sshed in and ran mailq but it said the queue was empty. Then I rebooted the whole server, and the mail came flooding into my mailbox.

Today, I realized that again, I hadn't received email in about a month. Again, my mail queue was empty and again, a server reboot brought me a flood of emails. What could be going on here? If the mail isn't trapped in the queue, where is it getting stuck and how do I fix this?